# I want to transfer a domain to another registrar

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I have a domain registered at hostgator.com which would expire in a day.Now i want to use godaddy for the domain, what would be the best practise for me:
1. Wait for the domain to expire and then register it to godaddy
OR,
2. transfer the domain to godaddy before it's expiry

Would the the domain be immediately available at godaddy after it's expiry at hostgator or will it take some time.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a domain expires its not a simple case of re-registering, it goes into several periods after where the person or business can renew the account. If you plan to use the domain again then you should proceed with renewing it, and then transferring.

Qoute from an answer I left a few months back:
 [Domain Expiration when transfer is processing, will I lose it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43413/domain-expiration-when-transfer-is-processing-will-i-lose-it/43418#43418)

> Expiring Domains Explained
>
> Whenever a domain expires you do not lose your domain straight away,
>   ICAN has policy's in place that gives registers more time to renew
>   their domain once it has expired. ICANN refers to these as a Grace
>   Period and a Redemption Period. There is actually 2 stages until
>   entering the 3rd stage where your domain becomes registerable to other
>   people.
>
> Stage 1: Grace Period
>
> As soon as your domain expires your domain enters the Grace Period,
>   this stage means that you can renew your domain within 30 days without
>   additional charges apart from the standard renewal cost set by the
>   registrar. No one else can take your domain during this period and
>   some domain registrars even allow you to transfer during this period
>   while many do not. Failing to renew your domain during the standard
>   allowance of 30 days enters you into the Redemption Period.
>
> Stage 2: Redemption Period
>
> Once 30 days has passed and the domain in question remains
>   nonrenewable then it enters the redemption period, this stage of the
>   expiring process normally lasts 40 days. During this period again like
>   the Grace Period no one can register your domain and it is still
>   locked to the original person who registered it. But unlike the grace
>   period charges to renew the domain will be much more than just the
>   renewal cost and this varies from registrar to registrar.
>
> Stage 3 & 4: Pending Delete & Dropped Domain
>
> Failing to renew your domain during the grace and redemption period
>   will enter the final stage of it being released into the public, this
>   is referred to as pending delete and dropped. Whenever a .com or .net
>   TLD is due to drop it will drop around 11AM to 12:15 PST, It is still
>   renewable during these last final moments.
>
> Conclusion
>
> You actually have around 70 days to renew your domain, it doesn't
>   matter if its in process of being transferred the domain will still be
>   yours but will require renewing once transfer has completed.